# Issues in Vagrant setup on Windows Vista 32bit

Tags: vagrant, windows-vista

I have downloaded the below version and trying to install them using the setup. But nothing is happening.

**Installer**: vagrant_1.6.5.msi, vagrant_1.7.0.msi and vagrant_1.7.2.msi

**My Machine Configuration:**
Windows Vista 32 bit with 3GB RAM (With NO virtualization/Hyper-V support)

Any pointer to this. Any other ways to view the logs why it is not getting installed.

Meanwhile, just to give a try, I tried with "Vagrant_1.4.3.msi" this got installed but my vagrant version criteria is 1.7.x (See above)

Please help.

Comment: With those spects I would not even try it. Your hardware is IMHO too old for such things. By the way this question would better fit on http://superuser.com

Comment: surprisingly, Vagrant website does-not mention anything about platforms, configurations etc. They only mention about "Universal (32 and 64-bit)".
Nothing on, old OS etc.

Answer (score 2):

Install vargrant_1.7.4.msi via Command line Interface using the following code:

msiexec /i C:\Users\username\Documents\shell\vagrant_1.7.4.msi /passive /norestart

and then restart the computer manually for the changes to take place